# Set color style to tinyMCE text selection through the API

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am trying to apply a specific color to the selected text in the editor using the tinyMCE api (jQuery version)

This is what I am doing so far:

```
var node = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
tinyMCE.DOM.setStyle(node, 'color', '#FFF');
```

The problem is this will change the color of the whole node instead of just the marked text.
Is there a way to apply the color only to the marked text through the tinyMCE API?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the answer. In case someone else is stuck here I'll post the solution.

```
// Registering the special format with a variable
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.register('custom_format', {inline : 'span', styles : {color : '%value'}});

// Applying the specified format with the variable specified
tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.apply('custom_format', {value : 'red'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this simple solution. Set the selection background / foreground color

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    theme_advanced_text_colors : "FF00FF,FFFF00,000000",
    ...
});
```